# How to properly set sharing permissions on a new file in a GAS-based form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have had some inconsistent results using GAS to set sharing for files created in the script, from an uploaded blob.
Gobally, the GAS script serves an Html form, collects the uploaded file, and makes some logging and processing. It is a heavily modified version of this https://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files adapted for report submissions from students.

The only clues I have so far are related to the position of the line that sets the sharing, relative to the lines in which the file is created:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dropbox);

// Get the blob
var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';'))
var bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7))
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, filename)

// Create a folder for the file if it does not exist
try{
  var subFolder =  folder.getFolder(tp);
}
catch(e) {
  var subFolder =  folder.createFolder(tp);
}
var file = subFolder.createFile(blob) // Create the file
```

From this point on, strange things happen. I have narrowed down the problem to the actual line that sets the sharing:

```
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW)
```

If this is immediately after the file creation, it works only some times. Over 200 reports have been submitted, and ~50% of them are visible to anyone with the link, while the rest are only shared privately.

Whether these permissions are set or not, everything else completes successfully. So i have no error log to know for sure what is going on.

By moving this line to the end of the function, subsequent submissions have properly set the permissions:

```
// .... processing lines that include logging to a spreadsheet, sending emails, and setting other permissions.

file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW)

return "OK";
```

My guess is that, for some reason, the time between file creation and permission modification affects the effectivenes of the .setSharing() line.

One hypothesis is that the file may be inheriting the parent folder's permissions (which is not public) with "lag". In other words, the permissions set by the .setSharing() function would be overwritten by some obsecure inheritance function behind file creation line:

```
 var file = subFolder.createFile(blob) // Create the file
```

The "default" permissions must surely be set at some point, but there is no "flush" function, that I know of, to force or wait for this to happen (such as the one used in Google Spreadsheets).

EDIT: i have found a thread where similar "non determinism" occurs, involving permission inheritance from the parent folder (see [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759387)).

I would like to know how to make sure that permissions are always set correctly.

Cheers 
:)

Comment: For your situation, how about using [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)? By using Drive API, when the file is created, the permission can be also included.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment Tanaike. I have followed the link, but it is not clear to me how to use the Drive API in my script. ¿Could you provide an example? Regards

Comment: Yes. You can see the sample for using Drive API from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611185/ways-to-reduce-search-time-on-google-script/50614767#50614767).

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the following, and the file is created correctly, but permissions are once again not set on file creation. I have used this files resource with Drive.Files.insert:
` var filesResource = { 'title': fileName, 'mimeType': contentType, 'description': 'lab report', 'shared': true, 'permissions': [{"role": "reader", "type": "anyone", "withLink": true }]};`

Comment: I noticed that I misunderstand about the method of Drive.Files.Insert. Although The setting of permission is included in the request body, the permission can install for only the created files. When I tried it using Drive API v3, the error of ``The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.`` occurs. Namely, this indicates that it is required to create files before give the permissions. I'm really sorry.

Comment: So I would like to propose 2 workarounds. 1. It supposes that a folder is shared. When a file is created to the shared folder, the file is also automatically shared by the same condition of the folder. How about using this? 2. In your script, after ``var file = subFolder.createFile(blob)`` was run, it waits for a little time using ``Utilities.sleep()``. By this, after the file was completely created, it can give the permissions to the file.

Comment: #1 I have thought of making the parent folder publicly available, but it is rather important that the folder containing all submissions remain private. If subfolders are created at submissions, and are publicly shared at the same time, the issue persists, as folders are no different than files.

Comment: As for #2 it is a possibility, but the HTML form waits for the function to end, and so does the submitter, which requires a confirmation. This is sub-optimal, but could be a patch and i will test it. I have found this issue which seems to be related https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759387 to the "delayed" inheritance problem.

Comment: I will try to use Drive.Permissions.insert() instead of file.setSharing() and hope that the permissions are set consistently, and report back. Thank you for your effort @Tanaike it has been quite helpful.